# File size total and update counter

Tags: jquery, ajax, filesize

I need to calculate the total size of uploaded files and then reduce it from 10 as total available limit is 10MB only. Each time file upload/add it should reduce from remaining space.
For e.g. Initial limit 10 MB. I uploaded 1 file of 3 MB, remaining 7 MB. Now another file of 4 MB so, remaining should be 3 MB.

Question: Can I disable file upload button during upload? Even in case any file is uploading it should be disable and enable to add further files only when all the files finish uploading.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#addFile").click(function() {
    $("#my_file").click();
});

$("#my_file").change(function(e) {
    var files = e.target.files;

    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        ParseFile(f);
    }
    function ParseFile(file) {
        var filename = file.name.replace(/\..+$/, '');
        var filesize = file.size / 1024;
        filesize = (Math.round((filesize / 1024) * 100) / 100);
        var filetype = file.type.split('/').pop().toUpperCase();
        if (filetype == 'PDF' || filetype == 'JPEG' || filetype == 'JPG' || filetype == 'PNG') {
            $("#filedetails").append("<tr><td><strong>" + filename + "</strong></td><td>" + filesize + " MB</td><td>" + filetype + "</td><td><a href='#'>Delete</td></tr>");
        }
        else {
            alert('Only JPG, PDF n PNG files are allowed to upload.');
        }
    }
});
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>File Upload</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="fileupload.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" value="Add File(s)" id="addFile">
  <input type="file" id="my_file" style="display:none;" multiple="multiple" accept="image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg, application/pdf">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="1">
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Size</th>
  <th>Type</th>
  <th></th>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="filedetails"></tbody>
</table>
<div id="totalsize">Total Uploaded File Size(s): </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return filesize from ParseFile function to foreach loop, and sum up all together. But remember - if you want to send multiple files, you need to select all of them at once.

Of course there must be some validation to check if selected files are bigger than 10MB.

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
var maxSize = 10, // MB
    currentSize = 0,
    remainSize = 0;

$("#addFile").click(function() {
  $("#my_file").click();
});

$("#my_file").change(function(e) {
  var files = e.target.files;

  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
    if (ParseFile(f) === false) {
      alert('not enought space - there\'s only ' + remainSize.toFixed(2) + ' MB left');
      break;
    }
  }

  $('#totalsize span').text(currentSize.toFixed(2));
  $('#remainsize span').text(remainSize.toFixed(2));

  function ParseFile(file) {
    var filename = file.name.replace(/\..+$/, '');
    var filesize = file.size / 1024;
    filesize = (Math.round((filesize / 1024) * 100) / 100);
    var filetype = file.type.split('/').pop().toUpperCase();
    if (filetype == 'PDF' || filetype == 'JPEG' || filetype == 'JPG' || filetype == 'PNG') {
      if (currentSize + filesize >= maxSize) {
        return false;
      }
      currentSize += filesize;
      remainSize = maxSize - currentSize;

      $("#filedetails").append("<tr><td><strong>" + filename + "</strong></td><td>" + filesize + " MB</td><td>" + filetype + "</td><td><a href='#'>Delete</td></tr>");
    }
    else {
      alert('Only JPG, PDF n PNG files are allowed to upload.');
    }
  }
});
  });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>File Upload</title>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="fileupload.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="button" value="Add File(s)" id="addFile">
 <input type="file" id="my_file" style="display:none;" multiple="multiple" accept="image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg, application/pdf">
 <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="1">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Size</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th></th>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="filedetails"></tbody>
 </table>
 <div id="totalsize">Total Uploaded File Size(s): <span>0</span> MB</div>
 <div id="remainsize">Remain: <span>0</span> MB</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** Below is extended version of above code with 'delete' function implemented. **Refactoring is highly advisable.**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var maxSize = 10, // MB
  currentSize = 0,
  remainSize = 0;

function refreshSpace() {
 $('#totalsize span').text(currentSize.toFixed(2));
 $('#remainsize span').text(remainSize.toFixed(2));
}

$("#addFile").click(function() {
 $("#my_file").click();
});

$("#my_file").change(function(e) {
 var files = e.target.files;

 for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
  if (ParseFile(f) === false) {
   alert('not enought space - there\'s only ' + remainSize.toFixed(2) + ' MB left');
   break;
  }
 }

 refreshSpace();

 function ParseFile(file) {
  var filename = file.name.replace(/\..+$/, '');
  var filesize = file.size / 1024;
  filesize = (Math.round((filesize / 1024) * 100) / 100);
  var filetype = file.type.split('/').pop().toUpperCase();
  if (filetype == 'PDF' || filetype == 'JPEG' || filetype == 'JPG' || filetype == 'PNG') {
   if (currentSize + filesize >= maxSize) {
    return false;
   }
   currentSize += filesize;
   remainSize = maxSize - currentSize;

   $("#filedetails").append("<tr data-filesize='" + filesize + "'><td><strong>" + filename + "</strong></td><td>" + filesize + " MB</td><td>" + filetype + "</td><td><a class='delete' href='#'>Delete</td></tr>");
  }
  else {
   alert('Only JPG, PDF n PNG files are allowed to upload.');
  }
 }
});

$("#filedetails").on('click', '.delete', function(e) {
 var $parent = $(this).closest('tr'),filesize = $parent.attr('data-filesize');
 currentSize -= filesize;
 remainSize = maxSize - currentSize;
 refreshSpace();
 $parent.remove();
});
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>File Upload</title>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="fileupload.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="button" value="Add File(s)" id="addFile">
 <input type="file" id="my_file" style="display:none;" multiple="multiple" accept="image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg, application/pdf">
 <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="1">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Size</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th></th>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="filedetails"></tbody>
 </table>
 <div id="totalsize">Total Uploaded File Size(s): <span>0.00</span> MB</div>
 <div id="remainsize">Remain: <span>10.00</span> MB</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but if i am selecting files next time its removing the existing files

Comment: But if you select another files, previous will be remove from input and will not be sent. If You want to just display theirs sizes, you need to add array which will remember all selected files, and every change will be refreshed.

Comment: I am basically creating a file upload section. where user can upload some files and show into the table. user can select multiple files with multiple times till the time space is available. So, those files user have already selected i cannot remove if user is clicking on add files again

Comment: Perfect. Thanks ! Really appreciated your support. Can you also help me to work on delete link as well. If user is removing the specific file by clicking on delete button it should hide the file and based on it remaining space should adjust

Comment: I added 'delete' support with recalculating total size.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am working on ajax implementation on this to upload file

Comment: Hi I need some more help regarding ajax implementation to show loader n delete icon and also find the duplicate file and show the size remaining out of 10 MB